# Using namedtuple in zip/ list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm writing some code for certain finance-related concept illustration. Below is one instance of what I have; note that I've to repeat such piece of code like a dozen times, and hence the need for this question:

```py
payouts = [1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09]
yield_rates = [0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04]
present_values = [each[0]/(1+each[1])**i for i,each in enumerate(zip(payouts, yield_rates), 1)]
print("The present value is ", sum(present_values))
```

Now, if I was to bury this code in a package or if I addressed this code to programmers, this was all fine, but I really hate that I am using `each[0]` and `each[1]` in the `present_values` calculation in a code which is addressed to (mostly) non-programmers. With minimal changes, how can I possibly use something like `each.payout` and `each.yield_rate` in the `present_values` list comprehension calculation? I think I want to use [`namedtuples`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) ( something like `namedtuple('Entry', ['payout', 'yield_rate'])`) here, but I'm not sure how to proceed without bringing in extra baggage.

Comment: What happened when you tried to use a namedtuple? It has no extra baggage, of if so, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Frankly, I just couldn't use it with zip :/ (Sorry, I didn't mean baggage in terms of code performance, but rather code-readability or succinctness if you will)

Comment: Keep unpacking in the for-loop target list: `for i, (payout, yield) in enumerate(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you don't need to use a `namedtuple`. You can also use *tuple unpacking* instead of indexing:

```
present_values = [payout / (1 + yield_rate) ** i for i, (payout, yield_rate) in enumerate(zip(payouts, yield_rates), 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I aggree with `mkrieger1`'s answer, that you should just use unpacking, however, if you *did* want to use a `namedtuple` you could just do something like:

```
Entry =  namedtuple('Entry', ['payout', 'yield_rate'])

payouts = [1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09]
yield_rates = [0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04]
entries = map(Entry, payouts, yield_rates)
present_values = [
    entry.payout / (1 + entry. yield_rate)**i 
    for i, entry in enumerate(entries)
]
```

Likely, `payouts` and `yield_rates` should have been an `Entry` object of some kind (whether of a class generated by the namedtuple factory or just a handwritten class).

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that `map` has kind of a built-in `zip`.